# Is unihibited exhalation beneficial for someone with a contagious respiratory disease?

Tags: virology, pathology, breathing

If someone has a contagious respiratory disease (I'll refer to as CRD - eg. COVID, FLU, etc.) I'm wondering if the process of exhaling could be beneficial for them.

My first thought is that exhaling would be beneficial because expelling the virus from the lungs (which is the same process that makes it contagious) could lower the viral load in the lungs.  Instead of those virii replicating in their own lungs it would be expelled.  It would seem that wearing a mask in a case where a person has a CRD would be detrimental because the virus would be caught by the mask when they breathe out (which is why masks protect other people) but then could be re-inhaled when they breathe in.)

On the other hand, it could be that for someone to be contagious they would have such a viral excess that the amount they would re-inhale would not be significant.

It is clear that if someone might have a virus and be might be contagious should wear a mask around other people.  The question is, would such a person benefit from not wearing a mask when they are not around other people (in a closed room or car or outside away from people) or would it not make a difference?  For example, I've often seen people driving around in a car by themselves while wearing a mask.  It's not clear to me if this is a harmless practice or is detrimental to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

No, there isn't going to be any benefit to an infected person by allowing them to breathe out virus particles freely. The number of viral particles breathed out is tiny relative to the number captured in a diagnostic swab, which itself is tiny relative to the virus contained in the entire rest of the respiratory tract. Simple exhalation is just not an effective manner of removing virus.

**Longer answer**

Fabian et al 2008 measured exhaled virus from subjects with influenza.

> Concentrations in exhaled breath samples ranged from <48 to 300 influenza virus RNA copies per filter on the positive samples, corresponding to exhaled breath generation rates ranging from <3.2 to 20 influenza virus RNA copies per minute.

Granados et al 2017 estimated viral loads of influenza on the order of 10^5 to 10^8 copies per milliliter, median around 10^6.6 (from 200 microliter extracts of clinical samples).

There are 1440 minutes in a day, if we go from the top end that's 20*1440 = 28800 exhaled particles over an *entire day*, easily an order of magnitude less than would be picked up by a diagnostic swab and likely a fraction of a percent. That doesn't even account for the fact that a diagnostic swab is itself not taking any sizable fraction of the infected particles in that individual, nor that new particles are being generated throughout the day.

Wanting to confirm a bit, I went to another source. Milton et al 2013 collected particles of two sizes from breath exhalations, as well as swabs from the same subjects. Median swab concentrations were around 10^5 to 10^6 on different days, similar to those from Granados. Virus particles from the coarse and fine exhaled particles were much lower; the peak was in fine particles on the first day with a median over 30 minutes of 610 particles (plus another 23 in the coarse particles), the same as the high end of Fabian.

It is not feasible that these tiny numbers would have any influence on the severity of the infected individual's illness. If it were, you'd be much better off just getting a bunch of respiratory swabs (no, this won't actually work)! It is feasible, however, that these particles go on to infect others, and that's what mask-wearing is trying to avoid.

As far as people alone in cars, likely the main benefit to them is that by keeping their masks on rather than removing them repeatedly, they're avoiding contact between their hands and anything that's ended up on the mask, and avoiding bringing the mask that they'll breathe through into contact with whatever has ended up on their hands.

---

Fabian, P., McDevitt, J. J., DeHaan, W. H., Fung, R. O., Cowling, B. J., Chan, K. H., ... & Milton, D. K. (2008). Influenza virus in human exhaled breath: an observational study. PloS one, 3(7), e2691.

Granados, A., Peci, A., McGeer, A., & Gubbay, J. B. (2017). Influenza and rhinovirus viral load and disease severity in upper respiratory tract infections. Journal of Clinical Virology, 86, 14-19.

Milton, D. K., Fabian, M. P., Cowling, B. J., Grantham, M. L., & McDevitt, J. J. (2013). Influenza virus aerosols in human exhaled breath: particle size, culturability, and effect of surgical masks. PLoS pathogens, 9(3), e1003205.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Based on what you're saying, it seems a comparable analogy would be that when a fire spews out burning ashes, it can start other fires.  But keeping the sparks contained in the original fire is not going to make it burn any stronger.

Comment: While I don't doubt your short answer, I'm not sure I follow the long one, either.

Comment: @anongoodnurse The short form of the long answer is that the number of viral particles breathed out is tiny relative to the number captured in a simple swab, which itself is tiny relative to the virus contained in the entire rest of the respiratory tract. Simple exhalation is just not an effective manner of removing virus.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Senior moment... no, several minutes, there. :-/